# How to load custom test helpers in Ember 3.2 tests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I seem to be missing some info about how to register a test helper in Ember 3.2, looking for some guidance:

I'm trying to use a test helper ([see here](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/b00b5a190321c8236ee0e0fab200bf65)) which I've placed in my `tests/helpers` directory, and am trying to reference it in a test:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupRenderingTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { render } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import setupMirage from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support/setup-mirage';

module('Integration | Component | my-component', function(hooks) {
  setupRenderingTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);

  test('it renders nothing by default', async function(assert) {
    const company = server.create('company');
    this.pushMirageRecordsToStore(); // this doesn't work
    await render(hbs`{{my-component}}`);

    assert.equal(this.element.textContent.trim(), '');

  });
```

When `this.pushMirageRecordsToStore()` is called the error is:

```
TypeError: this.pushMirageRecordsToStore is not a function
```

Which leads me to believe the `registerAsyncHelper` helper in that link is not being called.

My question is how do I make the Ember test framework call registerAsyncHelper in that test helper so I can do `this.pushMirageRecordsToStore()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering a test helper and calling it `pushMirageRecordsToStore` then it should be available as a global so you should be able to access it in your tests as `pushMirageRecordsToStore();`, not `this.pushMirageRecordsToStore();`.

There's good documentation on registering test helpers in the ember docs [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/test-helpers/#toc_custom-test-helpers).

p.s. just to confirm, the helper you shared in the link was called `pushMirageDbIntoStore` but here you call `pushMirageRecordsToStore`. The name will need to be identical :-)

Comment: haha yes it's true, i did rename it :)
I've tried calling the function as a global, like pushMirageRecordsToStore(), but I get an error saying "Cannot call function schema on undefined", which means I have to pass in the server and store parameters. This makes me believe the call to register async helper is not being invoked?

Comment: Can you call it and pass the `server` and `store` params?

Comment: The fact that you're getting errors from inside `pushMirageRecordsToStore` makes me think it is being called and is being registered correctly now :-)

Comment: yup it's getting called but doesn't the error suggest that it's not being called from registerAsyncHelper, as it builds the params? I can definitely call it with the params, but that would make registerAsyncHelper redundant, which is what I'm trying to figure out :p

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... `registerAsyncHelper ` is what makes it globally available in your tests. It registers the function as a global. Perhaps you could put together a twiddle that I could look at?